# Why is the main queue misbehaving inside dispatchMain()?

Tags: macos, grand-central-dispatch

The following program:

```swift
import Foundation

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("(1) on main thread: \(Thread.isMainThread)")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // executed on a different thread!
        print("(2) on main thread: \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
}

dispatchMain()
```

prints:

```
(1) on main thread: true
(2) on main thread: false
```

This is odd because the main dispatch queue is supposed to be a serial queue that executes tasks only on the application's main thread. Replacing `dispatchMain()` with `CFRunLoopRun()` yields the expected result, with both tasks running on the main thread. So what is the intended use of `dispatchMain()`, and how is it affecting the code above?

Comment: Main Queue IS bound to Main Thread.
Main Thread IS NOT bound to Main Queue.

https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2016/06/03/queues-are-not-bound-to-any-specific-thread/

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Nice link!

Comment: In the example above, the main queue _isn't_ bound to the main thread.

Comment: According to Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide: "Tasks added to this queue are performed serially _on the main thread_ itself." However, the man page for `dispatch_main()` states: "blocks submitted to the main queue in applications using dispatch_main() are not guaranteed to execute on the main thread." So it appears the latter is true, though for Cocoa applications you can always avoid `dispatch_main()`: set up the run loop via `CFRunLoopRun()` or `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop.run()` and it will enforce Apple's documented behavior.